# Percentage Option in CSS Background Image

Tags: css, image, background

Can someone please let me know what the 20% does in the following style?!

```
background: url('header.jpg') no-repeat 20%;
padding:500px 0;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sets the `background-position-x` property of the background image 20%, which moves the image to the right by 20%. Although using it with `background-size: cover` and `background-attachment: fixed` doesn't make a lot of sense.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

Answer (score 1):

it should be position of background image:

> background: color image position/size repeat origin clip attachment initial|inherit;

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: Thanks for that, I have a feeling it was positioning but wasn't 100% sure. That link sorted it for me!